# How to solve this non-autonomous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about the resolution of a differential equation. I have the answer but i don't understand how to find this solution.

Consider the following system :

$$\frac{d\omega}{dt}= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\beta_v(t)}{\lambda}-\mu_v(t) & 0 \\ \frac{\beta_h(t)}{\lambda} & -(\mu_h(t)+\gamma(t))
\end{pmatrix}\omega$$

which has fundamental matrix :

$$\Psi(t) = \begin{pmatrix} exp(\frac{1}{\lambda} \int_{0}^{t} \beta_v(s)ds-\int_0^t \mu_v(s)ds) & 0 \\f(t) & exp(-\int_0^t(\mu_h(s)+\gamma(s))ds\end{pmatrix}$$

where $$f(t)=exp(-\int_{0}^{t}(\mu_h(s)+\gamma(s))ds)(\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{t}\beta_h(s)exp(\frac{1}{\lambda} \int_{0}^{t} \beta_v(\tau)d\tau+\int_{0}^{t}(\mu_h(\tau)+\gamma(\tau)-\mu_v(\tau))d\tau)ds)$$

I can't calculate this fundamental matrix.. I tried the diagonalisation to calculate a matrix exponential but i don't find the same result..

Can you help me ?

Thank you,

Lehinig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe you need any special results to find the solution for this differential system under pretty reasonable assumptions. Observe that the first component is independent, i.e. we can simply write that $\omega_1(t)$ solves

$$\dot{\omega}_1(t) = \left[ \frac{1}{\lambda}\beta_v(t) - \mu_v(t) \right] \omega_1(t).$$

Assuming the integrability of the coefficient, the solution must be

$$\omega_1(t) = \omega_1(0)\;\mathrm{exp}\left( \int_{0}^t \frac{1}{\lambda} \beta_v(s) - \mu_v(s)\, ds \right).$$

We now have a known solution for $\omega_1(t)$ so we can treat that as known.
Therefore we may treat $\omega_2(t)$ as a solution to the non-homogenous linear differential equation

$$\dot{\omega}_2(t) + (\mu_h(t)+\gamma(t)) \omega_2(t) = \frac{1}{\lambda} \beta_h(t) \omega_1(t).$$

Assuming the integrability of the coefficient (once again) we now use variation of parameters. Define

$$\omega_2(t) = v(t)\; \mathrm{exp}\left(-\int_0^{t} \mu_h(s)+\gamma(s)\,ds \right).$$

Substituting this in to DE for $\omega_2(t)$ gives

$$\dot{v}(t)\; \mathrm{exp}\left(-\int_0^{t} \mu_h(s)+\gamma(s)\,ds \right) = \frac{1}{\lambda} \beta_h(t) \omega_1(t).$$

At which point you can resolve $v(t)$ by direct, painful integration with initial condition $v(0) = \omega_2(0)$ and complete the solution. Specifically

$$v(t) = \omega_2(0) + \int_0^t \mathrm{exp}\left(-\int_0^{\tau} \mu_h(s)+\gamma(s)\,ds \right) \frac{1}{\lambda} \beta_h(\tau) \omega_1(\tau)\, d\tau.$$

Substitute our expression for $\omega_1$

$$v(t) = \omega_2(0) + \omega_1(0) \int_0^t \frac{1}{\lambda} \beta_h(\tau) \mathrm{exp}\left(-\int_0^{\tau} \mu_h(s)+\gamma(s)\,ds \right)\mathrm{exp}\left( \int_{0}^\tau \frac{1}{\lambda} \beta_v(s) - \mu_v(s)\, ds \right) \, d\tau.$$

and simplify

$$v(t) = \omega_2(0) + \omega_1(0) \int_0^t \frac{1}{\lambda} \beta_h(\tau) \mathrm{exp}\left(\int_0^{\tau} \frac{1}{\lambda} \beta_v(s) -\mu_h(s)-\gamma(s)-\mu_v(s)\,ds \right)\, d\tau.$$

I think my $\tau$ and $s$ have flipped roles in your integral, but same idea. Backsubstitute $v(t)$ into $\omega_2(t)$ and you are done.